# Equality of mixed partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Is the following statement $$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \, \partial y}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \, \partial x}$$ always true? If not what are the conditions for this to be true?

Comment: Very nice result here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/47885/27978

Comment: Just a remark: Note that in a broader sense, if you replace the derivatives with covariant derivatives on a Riemannian manifold (concider that everything is happening on a sphere, for example), the difference between $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ is the *curvature* (at least when differentiating vector fields). So, you can interpret the above identity as saying that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is "flat".

Comment: Here, you can find the more generalized version of the above theorem. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3439436, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346161

Comment: And here's the standard counterexample with $f_{xy}(0,0) \neq f_{yx}(0,0)$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219759/show-that-both-mixed-partial-derivatives-exist-at-the-origin-but-are-not-equal

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Second order partial derivatives commute if $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^2$ (i.e. all the second partial derivatives exist and are continuous). This is sometimes called Schwarz's Theorem or Clairaut's Theorem; see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives).

Answer (score 5):

This is true in general if $ f \in \mathcal{C}^2 $. This has a name: [symmetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives). More formally, it is known as Clariut's Theorem or Schwarz's theorem.