# Partial derivative condition

Tags: partial-derivative

Does $\frac{\partial^2{z} }{\partial{x} \partial{y} }$ always equal $\frac{\partial^2{z} }{\partial{y} \partial{x}}$?

I find myself in situations where using one will be easier and faster than the other.

Comment: You have a plate in which one candy and one biscuit are available. Eat either first candy then biscuit or vice versa. Final answer will be empty plate! Haha.. sorry

Comment: Quite funny. Thanks for the illustration. But this is maths you know. @learningstudent

Comment: @coreyman317 The link you cite points out the answer is "no."  The OP asks if they are *always* equal.

Comment: It's a well-known fact in multivariable calculus that the mixed partials are equal.

Comment: @MichaelRybkin: ...under some **conditions**! See here for a well-known counterexample: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219759/show-that-both-mixed-partial-derivatives-exist-at-the-origin-but-are-not-equal

Comment: @HansLundmark That's absolutely correct. I forgot to mention that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are probably dealing with elementary functions, this will hold true. But I will point out some caveats. Let's not forget the obvious: the second partial derivatives must exist at the given point you are evaluating the expression.

Additionally, if the partials are *continuous* at that point, and analogously, if the $n^{\text{th}}$ partials are continuous at the point of evaluation, the $n^{\text{th}}$ degree mixed partials will commute. However, if this is not the case (it is most of the time), then you will have to resort to other methods to determine the truth of this statement.

Here's an example where Clairaut's Theorem [fails](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_rMDSE19FE).

Comment: Isn't the continuity of second partials only a *sufficient* condition for mixed partials to be equal, not a *necessary* one? In other words, is the statement “**must** be continuous” really true?

Comment: You are correct. I will update the answer.